# How is a signal uncatchable (e.g. sigkill)? What goes on under the hood of linux?

Tags: linux, process, signals

I understand there are catchable and uncatchable signals. However, it seems that both types of signals get sent to processes by the OS. What makes uncatchable signals uncatchable? Is it the signal handler that catches signals, and because no signal handler is written to handle an a particular signal (e.g. sigkill), that it becomes uncatchable? If that's true, can I conclude that it is possible to catch an uncatchable signal by writing a signal handler?

Comment: When a signal queue is non-empty, delivering unmasked signals to process-defined signal handlers is only one of the possible actions that kernel code can take.

Comment: Is it possible to simplify your answer in almost layman's terms?

Comment: Signals don't just automatically run signal handlers.  There's kernel code that looks up the signal handler function from a table, saves the thread context, creates a new context where (signal information is in registers or on the signal stack, the instruction pointer is to the beginning of the signal handler, and the stack pointer is to the signal stack) and then context switches to that thread so the signal handler runs.

Comment: But the kernel can choose not to run the "start signal handler" logic, and do something else instead.  Like just mark in the kernel process list that recipient process is suspended (`SIGSTOP`), or (`SIGKILL`) kill it and start notifying drivers that fds got closed.  You can put a signal handler in the signal handler table, but if the kernel never reads from that table entry, you won't handle anything.

Comment: If you mean your signal handler runs in user space then I'd answer No. The kernel will catch the signal and kill the process before it even notices it was killed.

Comment: Some few signals are uncatcheable. Example is SIGKILL. It tells the OS/kernel to directly kill the process, no questions asked

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't catch the uncatchable signals as it is always caught by the default handler implemented by the kernel.
**SIGKILL** always terminates the process. Even if the process attempts to handle the **SIGKILL** signal by registering a handler for it, still the control would always land in the **default** SIGKILL handler which would terminate the program.
This is what happens when you try to shut down your system. 
First, the system sends a **SIGTERM** signal to all the processes and waits for a while giving those processes a *grace period*. If it still doesn't stop even after the *grace period*, the system forcibly terminates all the process by using **SIGKILL** signal.